# ''hello'' ++ ''world'' doesn't work in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Just want to clarify that it's my first day programming, and I realise how dumb this question is :D

1) Why doesn't it work?

```
ghci>''hello'' ++ ''world''

<interactive>:40:1: error
    * Syntax error on ''hello''
      Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
    * In the Template Haskell quotation ''hello''

ghci>''hello'' ++ '' '' ++ ''world''

<interactive>:41:17: error: parse error on input '''
```

Should I add something in the texteditor to make it work? Or did I just do some rookie mistake?

2)

```
ghci> ''Steve'' !! 2

<interactive>:42:2: error
    * Syntax error on ''Steve''
      Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
    * In the Template Haskell quotation ''Steve''
ghci>[1,2,3,5,8] !! 2
3
```

When I do these commands with numbers it works, but not with characters. I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please inline the code fragment (as text, *not* as image), etc. If later the link dies, the content is still available.

Comment: Furthermore the two screenshots seem not related at all.

Comment: The title _Haskell; extreme beginner questions_ is unfortunately not very informative. Please change it to reflect what you actually ask.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll follow your advices the next time I ask a question!

Comment: In my defense; I barely understand the connection between the editor and the terminal. That's why I also showed the texteditor (in case I had to add something there)

Comment: @TobiasBernhardt Please make sure to check out the [stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stackoverflow works on principles that are quite different from other types of websites you might be familiar with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings are surrounded by **double quotes** (like `".."`), not *two* single quotes (as in `''..''`). You thus should use `"` instead of `'`.

For example:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> "hello" ++ "world"
"helloworld"
Prelude> "hello" ++ " " ++ "world"
"hello world"
```

This is specified in the [*Haskell report 2010 section on 'Character and String Literals'*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-200002.6):

> Character literals are written between single quotes, as in `'a'`, and **strings between double quotes, as in `"Hello"`**.

Based on [this article](https://chrisbracco.com/curly-quotes/), one can write *straight double quotes* on a Mac keyboard with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, which is the way it is organized on a "standard" querty keyboard:

> On any typical keyboard, simply press <kbd>'</kbd> for a straight single mark (`'`) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> for a straight double mark (`"`).

Based on [@M.Aroosi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246049/hello-world-doesnt-work-in-haskell/52246074?noredirect=1#comment91441651_52246074), for a UK querty keyboard, the `"` is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: God damn I'm an idiot. Apparently my mac doesn't even have these quotes... So I guess I must copy paste them in the future. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: Is it okey to use this thread in the upcoming days to ask even more basic questions, or should I create a new thread every time I ask a bunch of questions? I couldn't find a existing thread for 'Haskell beginning questions'

Comment: @TobiasBernhardt: isn't this Shift+single quote key?

Comment: @TobiasBernhardt: I think the policy is to ask one question per, well, question. Since otherwise the question becomes a "package" of questions, and a user that later searches, will get all kinds of "*noise*" that is not relevant.

Comment: @TobiasBernhardt Stack Overflow is not a forum—it has no “threads”, and [each question should be its own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). In fact, this question should actually have been two questions.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to be sure, so I don't accidentally spam the forum

Comment: @TobiasBernhardt pretty hard to imagine that you can't type double quotes on your keyboard.  What country are you from?  It's probably shift+single quote like William says.  (Just making sure you heard him)

Comment: If your computer is set to UK English qwerty keyboard layout, then double quotes would be `Shift`+`2`

Comment: @TobiasBernhardt be sure to mark the question as answered (by clicking the check mark), also check out the [haskell tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) for useful stuff and FAQs. Have fun learning haskell!

Comment: Thanks for all the help once again! :)
I'll mark it as answered